# Android app not loading index page after creating .apk file on the device

Tags: android

In Chrome browser using IIS server in desktop application loading working perfect but, when I am creating android app for the same application. it is not event emulator `index.html` page not loading. any help..?

Project structure [image: file]

Comment: .............what? This question needs way more information. Are you trying to open a WebView in your app? Are you trying to open the webpage on a mobile browser?

Comment: Yes enabled `WebView`

Comment: have created static `index.html` content then created `.apk` file and installed on the device. the static page `index.html` loading on Android device.

Comment: Loading `index.html` from device or from external url?

Comment: From the `device` only.

Comment: Search "Android WebView load local HTML"

Comment: I think this is i need to add  `getSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);` for the `WebView`